# E886: Can't rename viminfo file to /home/kjeld/.viminfo!

Tags: 16.04, vim

I have started to use a ubuntu 16.04 server, and set it up exactly the same way as my 14.04 servers (and conceptually like my 10.04 and 12.04 servers)

Now if I run `sudo vi` I get this **error** when exiting:

```
E886: Can't rename viminfo file to /home/kjeld/.viminfo!
```

My homedir is on NFS and of course root cannot write to that.
Also on my old servers, root cannot write to `/home/kjeld/.viminfo` but they do not write an error message.

Anyone have an idea on what is new/changed with ubuntu 16.

vi maps to /usr/bin/vim.basic

Comment: Use `sudoedit` or `sudo -H vi`